# Bitmap to image conversion

Tags: c#

more information to last post(being more specific)

hi, 
I want to take advantages from emgucv and at the same time agorge.net.

Problem I am facing is type conversion

```
//EMGUCV

Image<Bgr, Byte> image1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>("file.jpg"); //read the image

// AFORGE.net
 system.drawing.Bitmap image2 = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("file.jpg");
```

How can i interchange these two types.

Bitmap->image (to base class)

e.g.,

```
Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply(image1.Bitmap);

now want to use
ImageViewer.Show(grayImage, "test"); //error
```

regards,
shahzad

Comment: Have a look at the most basic constructor for Bitmap in order to create an instance from an Image: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts25csc8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a System.Image.Bitmap class *is* an Image class.  See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) for more info.  [System.Drawing.Image is an abstract base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx).

As far as using AForge goes, you can use the [grayscale class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm) to convert to grayscale:

```
// create grayscale filter (BT709)
Grayscale filter = new Grayscale( 0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721 );
// apply the filter
Bitmap grayImage = filter.Apply( image );
```

AForge's Grayscale class takes a Bitmap instance in the Apply call, so you can simply use the Bitmap.FromFile method.

Edit: some more info on using AForge to convert to gray scale

Comment: +1, i was just writing that. Image is the base class for Bitmap.

Comment: Yeah--not totally sure if this answers the OP's post, but knowing Image is ABC definitely helps ;)

Comment: thanx for answer. but agin how can

Comment: The only similarity between `System.Drawing.Image` and `Emgu.CV.Image` is the name.

Answer (score 0):

Emgu CV's Image class has a [`ToBitmap()`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.1.0.0/document/html/058c70e1-9b5c-5e54-0e43-63a761ede9f7.htm) method.

So it's as trivial as:

```
image1.ToBitmap();
```

Comment: thanx , i just converted as  Image<Gray, Byte> image2 = new Image<Gray, Byte>(grayImage); and is working.